# Which is more evolved Rays or Sharks

Tags: evolution

I know the Theory of evolution explains that life transforms to become more complicated, sophisticated so that it's more equiped for survival, Just like *the survival of the fittest*, the fittest are the evolved and always survive

I learnt that rays evolved from sharks, but I see sharks eating rays in documentarys, Infact rays are afraid of sharks, they are nothing compared to killer sharks

I also learnt that by skeleton comparison chicken evolved from dinosaur, but dinosaur are like gods to chicken

If man evolved from animals, we've become wiser and they've become pets

What really is evolution speaking, evolved animals do they become stronger than their competitor or weaker?

From unicellular organism to complex organisms, is the pattern of evolution going forward or backward or no pattern

Thanks for your answer

Comment: "more evolved" is not a biologically justified statement. See answers here https://biology.stackexchange.com/questions/832/what-is-meant-in-biology-by-the-term-evolved.

Comment: Hi Aderinsola, welcome to Biology.SE. There is no such thing as "more evolved". It is just the diversity among organisms being shaped by their environment, their way of living, and so on over thousands of years. We might be "more evolved" than those tiny microorganisms, but come to think about it, we cannot survive inside glaciers or in volcanoes—two behaviours noted in several bacteria. There is no connection between progress and evolution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Evolution isn't a contest between two species, it's the interaction between a species and its overall environment. The only real measure of evolutionary "success" is the ability to leave behind offspring that survive to have still more offspring.

Tyrannosaurus Rex may have been bigger, stronger, and fiercer than any chicken, but apparently something changed in the environment that interfered with its ability to leave behind offspring. Maybe it was a meteor striking the earth and changing the climate. Giant reptiles wouldn't do so well if the climate suddenly got colder. Smaller dinosaurs that had feathers might have done better. Clearly, in today's environment, chickens are able to produce billions and billions of offspring!

Sharks may eat rays, but they aren't eating *all* the rays! The rays are leaving lots of offspring behind, and so are the sharks. This means that both species are well adapted to the current environment.

> From unicellular organism to complex organisms, is the pattern of
>   evolution going forward or backward or no pattern

No pattern. Whatever adaptations allow more offspring to survive will tend to last, and traits that interfere with offspring surviving will tend to disappear.

A good web site for learning more about evolution is [Evolution 101](https://evolution.berkeley.edu/evolibrary/article/evo_01)